# How to solve distributional equation?

Tags: distribution-theory

What are the only solutions of a distributional equation:

$$xT'=0$$

Thanks. Any hint?

I know that $T'(\phi)=-T(\Phi')$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. What have you tried, what do you know? Can you solve the equation $xS=0$ in the space of distributions, think of the support of $S$.

Comment: Thank you. Solutions of $xS=0$ are in form: $c\delta_0$. What to do next...?

Comment: So $T' = c\delta_0$, hence ...

Comment: $T=cH$ where $H$ is Heavyside's step function?

Comment: Yes, plus a constant function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. By definition of the product and derivative of distributions
$$
0=(xT')(\varphi)=T'(x\varphi)=-T\big((x\varphi)'\big)=-T(\varphi+x\varphi'),
$$
for all $\varphi\in\mathscr D(\mathbb R)$.